# How do I make changes to web pages immediate in Bottle in Production?

Tags: python, bottle

So far I have been running Bottle in development from Wing.  But whenever I make a change I have to restart Bottle.

I know about, `run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)`.  According to this [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bottle#FastCGI),

"By default, Bottle does not support reloading of files. However there is an option to allow such a feature. Bottle does this by starting a new server in parallel to the one currently running, switching over to it, and then removing the older version."

This sounds like a really bad thing to me.  If I make a change on PHP, it is visible immediately.  If I have hundreds or thousands of users, this sounds expensive and it sounds dangerous.

If I run Bottle in fastCGI on Windows, mod_wsgi on Apache, or anything mentioned here, http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html.

Am I required to use the bottle `reloader=True` in Production?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you asking if there's a high performance penalty for using `reloader=True`?